# Extract URL's from a string using PHP if any of two special symbols in the URL should be treated as delimiters (the first characters followed by URL)?

Tags: php, url, preg-match, special-characters, preg-match-all

To extract URLs (not a perfect solution but I'm almost satisfied as performance counts) I use

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);
```

code to extract URLs. 
However, it's not a perfect solution for me as URLs should be forced to cut up to `]` or `"|"` if any of these two symbols met in the extracted URL.

I know these symbols are valid symbols in URLs, however for my case they should be invalid. 
How should the `preg_match_all` above be slightly modified to know about these two delimiters? 
Thank you.

Comment: Acccording to RFC ( http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html ), these two characters are declared as "unsafe" and should be encoded. Do you really have them in some URLs?. If you want to match them, replace `[:punct:]` by the list of "punct" characters minus these two char.

Comment: Thank you. But tried to replace  [^,[:punct:]\s] with [^,\|\s] (even for just one "|" ) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[:punct:]` is a short for ``` [!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_``{|}~] ```.

In your regex you are using a negated character class `[^,[:punct:]\s]` that could be written as: ``` [^!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_``{|}~\s] ``` (I've removed the first comma because it already exists and I've dupplicate backquote for highlight).

If you want to allow `]` and `|`, remove them from the character class:

```
[^!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\^_`{}~\s]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your explanation.